# Some arguments not working as intended in plotting a factor-smooth interaction in mgcv

Tags: r, plot, mgcv

I made a plot of a factor-smooth interaction constructed through `s(... bs = "fs")` in the `mgcv` package. It appears, however, that the `xlim` and `main` arguments (and a few other arguments) of `plot.gam()` are not working properly, although the same arguments for plotting other kinds of smooths work.

Here's an example.

**Update: I modified the example to better reflect the issue I have (2 Dec., 2014).**

```
library(mgcv)

# create toy data
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(
 x = runif(10 * 100),
 f = rep(paste0("f", 1:10), each = 100)
)
d$y <- 2 * d$x + 10 + rnorm(10 * 100)

# build a model
model <- gam(y ~ s(x) + s(x, f, bs = "fs"), data = d)
```

The following code, which produces the plot corresponding to the `s(x)` term above, limits the x axis and places the title, as intended.

```
plot(model, select = 1, xlim = c(0.4, 0.6), main = "Title")
```

[image]

However, the following code, which generates the plot corresponding to the `s(x, f, bs = "fs")` term above, does not limit the x axis or produce the title.

```
plot(model, select = 2, xlim = c(0.4, 0.6), main = "Title")
```

[image]

I suspect `mgcv::plot.gam()` fails to pass (some of) the arguments to `mgcv:::plot.fs.interaction()` or `mgcv:::plot.mgcv.smooth()` in some cases, but have not been able to figure out why it happens and how to fix it. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I admit this a bit of an brute force approach that basically does not "fix mgcv", but I think fixing mgcv is above my abilities.

```
with(d, plot(X=           seq(0,1,length=100), 
             gamPred.x2 = predict(model, 
                     newdata=data.frame(x1=mean(x1),
                                        x2=seq(0,1,length=100),
                                        f="f5")
        )))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is indeed similar to what I do now. The issue is that this approach plots predicted values but not the smooth itself. The problem (and the part I should've done better in the illustration above) is that x2 actually participates in other smooth terms. So if I calculate predicted values, they reflect all the terms that include x2. This is sensible to do as well, but I am also looking for ways to isolate the effects that are attributable to the factor-smooth interaction alone.

Comment: Examples presented with insufficient complexity to illustrate the real problem deserve insufficiently complex answers.

Comment: Right. Sorry for the oversimplification. I have just updated the question.